# Parse custom configuration file in C

Tags: c, parsing, configuration

I have to parse a custom configuration file with this structure:

```
# Begin with core containers.

ID          = 0 # STX container
Name        = "" # No name is necessary for a STX container.
Flags       = {STX}
Attributes  = {Status=0}
```

So I've written the following code in order to remove those comments (starting with #) and the inline comments. I don't know if I'm doing it the right way, it just seems (for me, not too much experience) a stupid way of doing it with many while loops.

```
void NextToken() {
   // Let's begin taking comments away!
   FILE* Source = fopen("defs.dat", "r");
   char* Buffer = calloc(MAXBUFLEN, sizeof(char));
   while (fgets(Buffer, MAXBUFLEN, Source)) {
    // If line starts with '#' it is a comment, so it must be ignored. If it's a newine it just has to be skipped.
    if (Buffer[0] == 35 || Buffer[0] == '\n')
        continue;
    // Now we have to delete inline comments
    int Pos = 0;
    while (Pos < strlen(Buffer)) {
        if(Buffer[Pos] == '#') {
            Pos++;
            while(Buffer[Pos] != '\n')  {
                Pos++;
                continue;
            }
            continue;
        }
        //Cool! now just let's print the output.
        printf("%c", Buffer[Pos++]);
    }
   }
}
```

The max size of the buffer is 256 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `calloc()` with `fgets()`, it adds nul terminator by itself: use `malloc()` instead. Also check for allocation errors and, maybe, use a meaningful name for `Buffer` (for example `line`).

```
char* line= malloc(MAXBUFLEN, sizeof(char));
if (line == NULL) {
    // Oops...
}
```

Also `fopen()` *may* fail then you should also check its return value:

```
if (fopen(...) == NULL) {
    // Oops
}
```

You should move the check for a line to ignore to a separate self-explicative function, that's why you felt the need to add a comment:

```
if (IsBlankOrComment(line))
    continue;
```

Implementing `IsBlankOrComment()` you should avoid hard-coded constants like `35`, you should add `#define` and use a character instead of its ASCII code:

```
#define COMMENT_DELIMITER '#'

bool IsBlankOrComment(char* line) {
    char* trimmedLine = TrimWhiteSpaces(line);

    return trimmedLine[0] != '\0'
        && trimmedLine[0] != COMMENT_DELIMITER;
}
```

For a possible implementation you can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122721/1207195). Do not forget to include `stdbool.h` if you're using `bool` (instead of `_Bool`).

You now have to remove in-line comments, what's better than `strchr()`? No need to manually loop through the string:

```
char* inlineCommentStart = strchr(line, COMMENT_DELIMITER);
if (inlineCommentStart != NULL) {
    *inlineCommentStart = '\0';
}
```

Note that it also deals with line with leading and trailing spaces, if you do not need it then you definitely should go with [Edward's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189141/13424) lovely implementation (which uses `strpbrk()`).

To print the line (without comment) you then just need:

```
puts(line);
```

No need to print character-by-character while searching the delimiter (BTW do not use `printf()` when what you need to print is just a single character!) Also note that calling `strlen()` in a loop is (probably) extremely inefficient because, if compile can't determine that string is constant in the loop, it will emit code to call `strlen()` for each iteration.

Do not forget to close the file when you're finished:

```
fclose(stream);
```

And to free allocated memory:

```
free(line);
```

In this case you should ask yourself IF you need dynamically allocated memory. If `MAXBUFSIZE` is a preprocessor constant then you can directly declare a local variable (check also for stack size issues):

```
char line[MAXBUFSIZE];
```

If your application isn't multi-threaded and you call this function more than once you may want to also consider to make it `static`. Finally do not forget to add `const` here and there, where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I see some things that I think could help you improve your code.

### Allow the user to specify input and output files

The input file name is currently hardcoded which certainly greatly restricts the usefulness of the program.  Consider using `argc` and `argv` to allow the user to specify file name on the command line.  Also, it would be nice to be able to send the output to a file.

### Fix memory leaks

The program allocates but never frees memory, leading to a memory leak of `MAXBUFLEN` bytes every time `NextToken()` is called.  If the value of `MAXBUFLEN` is really just 256, as suggested in the text, then it might be simplest to declare it on the stack instead and avoid explicit memory allocation.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Instead of hard-coding the constant 35 in one place and `'#'` in another, it would be better to use a `#define` or `const` and name them.

### Simplify the code

The code uses `printf("%c",...)` where it could simply use `putchar()` and eliminate the overhead of `printf` scanning the format string.  Also the loops, with three `continue` statements are not very easy to follow.  Here's what I'd propose instead:

```
void NextToken2(const char *filename) {
    FILE* Source = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (Source == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file \"%s\"\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    char Buffer[MAXBUFLEN];
    char *ptr;
    while (fgets(Buffer, MAXBUFLEN, Source)) {
        if ((ptr = strpbrk(Buffer, "#\n")) != NULL) {
            *ptr = '\0';
        }
        if (Buffer[0] != '\0') {
            puts(Buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose(Source);
}
```